# Count the number of digits with sizeof is missing one digit

Tags: c, sizeof

I want to verifiy that the user entered a 12digit number. To do this I'm using the sizeof operator. However the result is 11 for a 12 digit number. Why is that?

```
long long n;
printf("please enter a 12 digit number \n");
scanf("%lli", &n);
printf("size is %li", sizeof(n) / sizeof(long long)); // this prints 11
```

Comment: Have you read anything about what the sizeof operator does? How did you think this would give you the number of digits?

Comment: Nunbers are not **arrays**

Comment: The `sizeof` operator gives you the size in *bytes* of a type.

Comment: `sizeof` is not the tool you want for this job.

Comment: Furthermore the `sizeof` returns a value with the type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type and for which you need the `z` prefix to print (i.e. `%zu`). Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: also " `//this prints 11`" no it doesn't. It prints `1`

Comment: And I cannot believe that this prints 11. It should print 1

Comment: Not sure why it would return 11 opposed to 1 irregardless of what the input is.  `%li` is the wrong format for `sizeof` which should be `%zu`

Comment: Something to keep in mind as you learn programming is that computers do *not* store variables of type `int` internally as strings of decimal digits.  (The same is true of types `float` and `double`, by the way.)

Comment: log10(n) rounded up will give you the number of 10-base digits in a number.  Note, c only provides floating type versions of the base-10 logarithmic function and you can either use one of the floating type `ceil()` or add 1 to the log value and truncated to integer to round up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot measure the number of digits in a integer variable using `sizeof`: numbers not arrays. `sizeof(n)` evaluates to the number of bytes of the type of `n`, `long long`, which is `8` on most systems. `sizeof(n)` is the same as `sizeof(long long)`, hence `sizeof(n) / sizeof(long long)` should produce `1`. The correct conversion for `size_t`, the type of the `sizeof()` expression, is `%zu`, not `%li`, which expects a `long`, which for example has a different representation from `size_t` on 64-bit Windows systems.

You could simply use comparisons:

```
if (n < 100000000000)
    printf("number has less than 12 digits\n");
else
if (n > 999999999999)
    printf("number has more than 12 digits\n");
```

Also note than scanning for `%li` does not catch other problems: the user could enter a negative number, a `+` sign, and the number could have leading zeroes which would not count toward the digit count.

Here is a safer approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* read a 12 digit number, return 1 on success, 0 on failure */
/* dest must point to a char array with a length greater than 12 */
int get_card_number(char *dest) {
    for (;;) {
        char buf[80];
        char ch;

        printf("please enter a 12 digit number\n");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "unexpected end of file\n");
            return 0;
        }
        switch (sscanf(buf, " %12[0-9] %c", dest, &ch)) {
        case EOF:
        case 0:
            printf("invalid input\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            if (*dest == '0') {
                printf("no leading zeroes allowed\n");
                break;
            }
            if (strlen(dest) == 12)
                return 1;  // OK
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("too many characters\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator gives the size of the operand's *type* and is (usually) evaluated at compile time.

If you want to know if a value has at least 12 decimal digits (i.e. it's at least 100,000,000,000), you should compare it against that value.

```
if (n >= 100000000000) {
    // do something
```

If on the other hand you want to count the number of decimal digits, then count the number of times you can divide by 10 before the result is less than 10.

```
int digits=1;
long long temp = n;
while (temp >= 10) {
    temp /= 10;
    digits++;
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's not an answer as op asks to count the number of digits with sizeof operator  which of course is not possible.

Comment: @AllanWind The question is, do you believe it's our job to blindly answer questions as literally asked (no matter how meaningless), or to try to teach the OP and help them understand the issue they're actually interested in?

Comment: @SteveSummit I think it's very clear that Op wants a solution with `sizeof()`, and as such it's important to state that "it's not possible" as @chqrlie does below.  I know this comes across as pedantic but I do think there is a lot of value in those negative answers, and they usually require particular deep knowledge about the subject.  As `sizeof()` operators on types which cannot be created at run-time, I would expect it to _always_ be evaluated at compile-time (but not seeing it defined in specification) and hence no run-time has any bearing on what is evaluated too.

Answer (score 0):

Humans tend to think about numbers in terms of their decimal representations.  When we hear someone say "hundred", we think of the number 100.

But computers do *not* store integers like 100 internally as strings of decimal digits.  Computers store integers internally as *integers* in some range — and as an implementation detail, they're virtually always implemented at the hardware level in binary (base 2), not decimal.

If you were to write the little program

```
int i = 12345;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));
```

it will probably print 4.  That's obviously not the number of digits in the number 12345, and it's not the number of bits in its binary representation (`11000000111001`), either.  No, 4 is the number of *bytes* that an `int` variable takes up on your computer.  On most of today's computers, an `int` variable takes up 4 × 8 = 32 bits of memory.  And that 32-bit size stays the same regardless of the particular value that might currently be stored in it.